# Правильно ли определять уникальность файла по хешу первых 15кб его данных?

Tags: веб-программирование

Мы ведем проверку уникальность файла таким методом. Это правильный подход?

УТОЧНЕНИЕ

Все файлы - это аудио, фото и видео различных форматов.

Какова вероятность того, что первые 15 кб разных изображений, видео и аудио могут быть одинаковыми. Или этого недостаточно и необходимо взять 15 первых и 15 последних Кб данных?

Comment: А каков критерий "правильности" подхода? Очевидно, что все файлы у которых первые 15кб одинаковы, будут считаться одинаковыми. Но может быть кому-то (вам) так и нужно. Или, скажем, таких файлов в вашем контексте не может быть.

Comment: А откуда вам знать, что на 16-м килобайте не появится разница?

Comment: Вот и вопрос, какова вероятность того, что первые 15 кб разных изображений, видео и аудио могут быть одинаковыми.Или необходимо взять 15 первых и 15 последних Кб данных?

Comment: она ненулевая (как и ненулевая вероятность того, что хеши совпадут при разных данных). Точнее вряд ли кто-то определит. Если Вам нужна скорость определения того есть ли такой файл среди загруженных или нет - может еще поможет фильтр Блума - очень компактная и быстрая вероятностная структура

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае нет. Вдруг это будут текстовые файлы логов, например, которые дописываются. Или роман какого-то писателя, который тот периодически сохраняет. Но точно можно ответить лишь по Вашей конкретной задаче - вдруг у Вас есть какой-то дополнительный контекст задачи, который позволяет так делать.

Comment: Да, есть то, что все файлы - это аудио, фото и видео различных форматов.

Comment: ну надо просто по всем возможным форматам "пробежаться" и определить что в случае например, полного видео и усеченного с конца будут разные первые 15 кб. Или если позволяют ресурсы можно это фоном делать после загрузки - дубликаты устранять (если цель стоит уменьшить занятое пространство). Смотря какая задача - когда и для чего проверка на уникальность используется